# Как узнать количество ячеек в ряде и количество рядов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Есть svg документ, который состоит из квадратиков - похоже на шахматную доску. Нужно как-то посчитать количество рядов , и количество квадратиков в каждом ряде. 
Как можно реализовать такой подсчёт ? Возможно ли вообще на jquery автоматизировать такой подсчёт ?

В примере SVG 10 рядов в каждом и 10 ячеек, но могут приходить и другие svg.

Пример SVG :

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="аЁаЛаОаЙ_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">


  
<rect fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: а сам svg  в ответ добавить можете?

Comment: @ cyadvert , добавил пример. Там 10 на 10 . Но могут приходить разные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проходим по `rect` всего SVG. Создаем 2 массива: уникальных значений `x` и уникальных значений `y`.

Что-то типа такого:

```
var Xs = [];
var Ys = [];
$('#yourcalay rect').each(function() {
    if (thisX = $(this).attr('x')) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(thisX, Xs)<0) {
            Xs.push(thisX);
        }
    }
    if (thisY = $(this).attr('y')) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(thisY, Ys)<0) {
            Ys.push(thisY);
        }
    }
});
console.log('Columns: ' + (Xs.length+1));
console.log('Rows: ' + (Ys.length+1));
console.log('Cells: ' + ((Xs.length+1)*(Ys.length+1)));
```

Учтите, это будет работать только если у вас сетка. Любого формата, не обязательно квадратная, но сетка...

Answer (score 1):

Так как блоки квадратные, то координаты указывают на конкретный строку и столбец, достаточно разделить их на высоту или ширину.

Следовательно можно просто пробежаться по всем и заполнить таблицу, например так:

```js
var rects = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

var table = [];
for(var i=0,len=rects.length;i<len;i++){
  
    var col = rects[i].x.baseVal.value/rects[i].width.baseVal.value;
    var row = rects[i].y.baseVal.value/rects[i].height.baseVal.value;
    if(!table[row]) table[row]=[];
    
    table[row][col] = rects[i];
}

console.log(table,'rows:',table.length, 'cols:', table[0].length);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="аЁаЛаОаЙ_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">


  
<rect fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="50" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="100" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="150" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="200" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="250" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="300" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="350" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="400" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
<rect x="450" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

для варианта с разным количеством ячеек в строке

```js
var rects = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("rect"));
rects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.y.baseVal.value - b.y.baseVal.value || a.x.baseVal.value - b.x.baseVal.value
});
alert(rects.length);
rects = rects.reduce(function(a, b, c, d) {
  d[c + 1] && (b.y.baseVal.value == d[c + 1].y.baseVal.value ? a[a.length - 1] ++ : a[a.length] = 1);
  return a
}, [1]);
alert(rects);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="аЁаЛаОаЙ_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">



  <rect x="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>


  <rect x="400" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="50" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="100" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="150" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="200" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="250" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="300" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="350" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="400" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="150" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="200" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="250" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="300" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="350" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="400" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  <rect x="450" y="450" fill="#126031" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="50" height="50"></rect>
</svg>
```